# Validating that an uploaded file is a valid PEM file

Tags: php, openssl, php-openssl

I'm trying to figure out an effective/elegant way to validate that a user uploaded file is a valid pem file without relying on validating the extension. Anyone accomplish this or have any ideas?

Comment: In what way are you trying to validate the pem file? Are you just trying to validate that it looks like a pem file (it's just text with `begin certificate`, `end certificate` with a bunch of base64 between) or actually verify that the enclosed certificate is valid?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, jww. I value it, and I think I speak for the entire community when I say that writing it was a fantastic use of your time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use "openssl rsa" and parse its output

Wrong file:

```
$ openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in ./wrong.pem 
unable to load Private Key

140324790638432:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

Proper key

```
$ openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in ../proper.pem
Modulus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
```

so you can wrap openssl execution to  shell_exec(),parse output and check for "unable to load Private Key" to detect wrong certificate

Comment: I was able to run this, but wasn't able to use the -modules flag in my particular environment. FYI

Comment: You weren't able to run it, because its not about a module, but about the modulus, not the second u. This is something specific to the RSA algorithm.

Answer (score -3):

I use php file to verify my pem follow below steps,

1. Download file from [validate pem](http://pastie.org/10404954)
2. Change extension to FILENAME.php from FILENAME.txt
3. Move it to the folder where the .pem file is kept.
4. Write device token and pem file name .php file.
5. Open  terminal and run command "php FILENAME.php"

If it shows success means .pem file is correct.